# How to check whether a vector is a Fibonacci sequence of numbers

Tags: r, performance, vectorization

Background: Fibonacci numbers are a series of numbers in which each number ( Fibonacci number ) is the sum of the two preceding numbers. A simple example is: 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, etc.

I am trying to understand how can I detect whether a vector contains Fibonacci numbers or not. Is it possible to accomplish this through a vectorized operation (I mean without using a loop)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After the first element, the differences between elements in a Fibonacci sequence should *be* the sequence. So, an easy solution is

```
F1 = c(2,5,7,12,19,31)
F2 = c(2,5,7,12,18,31)

all(diff(F1)[-1]  == head(F1, -2))
[1] TRUE
all(diff(F2)[-1]  == head(F2, -2))
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: Now that this is just a result of rearranging the definition. If a(i)=a(i-1)+a(i-2) then a(i-2)=a(i)-a(i-1)

Comment: That should say "note" and not "Now". It doesn't matter too much but I think it sounds less dickish with the correction.